# Timing problems when accessing a GCM message

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a multi-player quiz application. I'm using GCM to send messages from my server to the devices. The registration is done by this code

```
//skeletonactivity.java   
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart(): Connecting to Google APIs");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    regId = registerGCM();
    appUtil=new ShareExternalServer();
    shareRegidTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = appUtil.shareRegIdWithAppServer(context, regId);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            shareRegidTask = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };
    shareRegidTask.execute(null, null, null);

    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "GCM RegId: " + regId);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SkeletonActivity.this,Quizform.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

// i have tried making the activity launch after sometime, so that the GCM message will be recieved. but there's no change.

```
}
public String registerGCM() {

    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    regId = getRegistrationId(context);

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {

        registerInBackground();

        Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                "registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId: "
                        + regId);
    }
    return regId;
}

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            SkeletonActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }

    return registrationId;
}
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void...Params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regId = gcm.register(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                        + regId);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;
                storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
            }
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
            return msg;
        }
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            SkeletonActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version" );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
    editor.commit();
}
```

The code for sharing with external activity is 
shareExternalServer

```
public class ShareExternalServer {

public String shareRegIdWithAppServer(final Context context,
                                      final String regId) {

    String result = "";
    Map paramsMap = new HashMap();
    paramsMap.put("regId", regId);
    try {
        URL serverUrl = null;
        try {
            serverUrl = new URL(Config.APP_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("AppUtil", "URL Connection Error: "
                    + Config.APP_SERVER_URL, e);
            result = "Invalid URL: " + Config.APP_SERVER_URL;
        }

        StringBuilder postBody = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry> iterator = paramsMap.entrySet()
                .iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry param = iterator.next();
            postBody.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                    .append(param.getValue());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                postBody.append('&');
            }
        }
        String body = postBody.toString();
        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;
        try {
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
            httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
            httpCon.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();

            int status = httpCon.getResponseCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                result = "RegId shared with Application Server. RegId: "
                        + regId;
            } else {
                result = "Post Failure." + " Status: " + status;
            }
        } finally {
            if (httpCon != null) {
                httpCon.disconnect();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = "Post Failure. Error in sharing with App Server.";
        Log.e("AppUtil", "Error in sharing with App Server: " + e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

the code for GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}
public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (Context ctxt) {
    return ctxt.getSharedPreferences("message",0);
}
public static boolean flag;
public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";
public String mess=" ";
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    sharedPreferences=  getSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType=gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mess= extras.getString("message");
            editor.putString("mess",mess);
            editor.commit();
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + mess);
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}
}
```

The above code gets the value from the broadcast receiver and stores it the string msg.
i try to access it as below in quizform.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("messages",0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quizform);
        txt = sharedPreferences.getString("mess","empty");
        Toast.makeText(this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The value of txt is empty, and so i get only a blank toast. 
The server sends the message as soon as it gets the regID. the code is:

```
<?php
//generic php function to send GCM push notification
function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
   //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
   $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
   $fields = array(
       'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
       'data' => $message,
   );
   // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
   define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "apikey");        
   $headers = array(
       'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
       'Content-Type: application/json'
   );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);               
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}


 function sendquestions()
{
$servername = " ";
$username = "  ";
$password = " ";
$dbname="  ";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
$pushStatus = "";   
$result= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM regid");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
$gcmRegID=$row['id'];}
$pushMessage = "hello";
if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {      
$gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
$message = array("message" => $pushMessage);  
$pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
}       
} 
//this block is to receive the GCM regId from external (mobile apps)
if(!empty($_GET["shareRegId"]))
{
$gcmRegID  = $_POST["regId"]; 
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO regid (id) VALUES('$gcmRegID')");
$retval = mysql_query( $mysqli, $conn );
mysqli_close($conn);
sendquestions();
exit;
} 
?>
```

Please do suggest ways to get over the delay . thanks

Comment: what is the main issue? If you meant msg get delay, the msg is not real time in GCM, there is no absolute guarantee on delivery time. Also you need to make sure your device is connected, use different collapsed key for your msgs.

Comment: I've tried all that., The device is connected, i just want to there seems to be a delay before the message is recieved. is there a way i can wait until i get the message?